# Typescript: Abstracting and/or inheriting the abstract constructor parameters signature(s) of the base class

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, constructor

Here are my failing feeble attempts so far.  (Note: code comments beginning with `// *` are typescript compiler error messages.

```js
interface DestructureArg {num:number}
class A {
  num:number
  constructor(carg?:number|DestructureArg)
  constructor(...args:any[]){
    if (args.length==0)
      this.num=0;
    else if (typeof args[0]=="number")
      this.num=args[0]
    else if (args[0].num)
      this.num=args[0].num
    else throw new Error('illegal constructor argument');
  }
}
// *Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter 
// *of type 'number | DestructureArg'.
//var a=new A("hi"); // compile error :)
```

So far so good.  The abstract signature `constructor(carg?:number|DestructureArg)` is enforced when `new`ing an instance, and the implementation signature is properly ignored.

This following derived class `B1`

```
class B1 extends A{
  constructor(carg:number|DestructureArg=0){
    super(carg)
  }
}
```

compiles but the abstract signature of `A` was used as the implementation, which doesn't satisfy the ability to abstract the abstract signature of A.

The following derived class `B2`

```
class B2 extends A {
  constructor(...args:any[]){
    super(...args)
  }
}
var b2=new B2("hi"); // runtime error :( "illegal constructor argument"
```

compiles but the abstract signature of `A` has not been inherited, so a runtime error is possible.

In the following class `B3` we try using an interface `ASig`, but that doesn't compile because it requires the signature in `ASig` to be actually implemented:

```
interface ASig {
  new (carg?:number|DestructureArg):any
}
// *Class 'B3' incorrectly implements interface 'ASig'.
// *Type 'B3' provides no match for the signature 
//    'new (carg?: number | DestructureArg): any'.
class B3 extends A implements ASig {
  constructor(...args:any[]){
    super(...args)
}
```

Perhaps adding another signature will help?  Nope.

```
interface ASig2 {
  new (carg?:number|DestructureArg):any
  new (...args:any[]):any
}
// *Class 'B4' incorrectly implements interface 'ASig2'.
// *Type 'B4' provides no match for the signature 
//    'new (carg?: number | DestructureArg): any'.
class B4 extends A implements ASig2 {
  constructor(...args:any[]){
    super(...args)
  }
}
```

In the following `class D` and `class E` we try using the typescript helper `ConstructorParameters<A>`.  However, neither succeeds.  (`E` tried to go partway in giving up abstraction by using a single parameter - it doesn't help.)

```
class C extends A{
  // *Type 'A' does not satisfy the constraint 'new (...args: any) => any'.
  // *Type 'A' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any): any'.
  constructor(...args:ConstructorParameters<A>){
    // *Type 'never' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
    super(...args)
  }
}
class D extends A{
  // *Type 'A' does not satisfy the constraint 'new (...args: any) => any'.
  constructor(carg:ConstructorParameters<A>){
    super(carg)
  }
}
```

As a next step I am examining a snippet from a [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/e03w88/getting_parameters_types_from_abstract_class/) post

```
abstract class Test {
    constructor(a: string, b: number) {

    }
}
type AbstractConstructorHelper<T> = (new (...args: any) => { [x: string]: any; }) & T;
type AbstractContructorParameters<T> = ConstructorParameters<AbstractConstructorHelper<T>>;

// Params resolved to [string, number]
type Params = AbstractContructorParameters<typeof Test>;
```

which might be helpful.  However, currently I don't understand the semantics or syntax on the r.h.s. of `AbstractConstructorHelper<T>`.

**Abstracting and/or inheriting the constructor parameters of the base class** ought to be extremely simple to achieve. **Is there an easy and clearly understandable way to do it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you'll consider this "easy and clearly understandable," but this works, basically declaring a constructor type that matches what you want, and then using **that** type by reference to tie together the various places you want to link together.

Here's a modified version of your example with C and D:

```
interface DestructureArg {num:number}

namespace Anmsp {
    export type Constructor = new (carg?:number|DestructureArg) => A
}

class A {
  num:number
  constructor(carg?:ConstructorParameters<Anmsp.Constructor>[0])

  constructor(...args:any[]){
    if (args.length==0)
      this.num=0;
    else if (typeof args[0]=="number")
      this.num=args[0]
    else if (args[0].num)
      this.num=args[0].num
    else throw new Error('illegal constructor argument');
  }
}

class C extends A{
    constructor(...args:ConstructorParameters<Anmsp.Constructor>){
      super(...args)
    }
  }

  class D extends A{
    constructor(carg: ConstructorParameters<Anmsp.Constructor>[0]){
      super(carg)
    }
  }
```

---

The following shows how the `namespace` features can be used to cleanly define and export multiple abstract signatures into a single type and share them across classes.

```
namespace Xsig{
  type Ctor1 = new (carg?:number) => any
  type Ctor2 = new (...cargs:string[]) => any
  type Ctor3 = new ({a,b}:{a?:bigint,b?:string}) => any
  export type XCtorParams=
    ConstructorParameters<Ctor1>
    |ConstructorParameters<Ctor2>
    |ConstructorParameters<Ctor3>
}

class X {
  constructor(...args:Xsig.XCtorParams){
  }
}
class Y extends X {
  constructor(...args:Xsig.XCtorParams){
    super(...args) 
  }
}
var x=new X({b:"hi"}) // compiles :)
var y=new Y({b:"hi"}) // compiles :)

var x=new X({a:"hi"}) // compile fails :)
var y=new Y({a:"hi"}) // compile fails :)
```

Comment: Yep, you're essentially aliiasing that expression which I'm carrying through. Honestly, I'd probably do it my way -- I find that over time adding multiple names for the same thing (even if they're shorter) is less good than using a single name for that thing (even if it's verbose, like `ConstructorParameters<...>`. But if this is a really fundamental construct and you can give it a good name that would be the right choice (IMO) in some cases too. Anyhow, looks like you're on your way!

Comment: Yes - and when scaling up to multiple abstract signatures the namespace offers the ability to bundle them all up into a single type.  That's possible to do in a `namespace` but not inside a single `interface` - `namespace` is superior.  Once we know it, it is easy.

Comment: I have a question about the upper half - the constructor returns `=>A`.  It confusing whether `A` refers to the `namespace,A` or to the `class A`.  Would `=> any` suffice?

Comment: `any` would suffice, but I'd always err on the side of more typing rather than less. Could rename the namespace or not use it at all, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface ASig {
  new (carg?:number|DestructureArg):any
}
declare type ACtorParams=ConstructorParameters<ASig>

class A {
  num:number
  constructor(...args:ACtorParams){
  if (args.length==0)
      this.num=0;
    else if (typeof args[0]=="number")
      this.num=args[0]
    else if (args[0].num)
      this.num=args[0].num
    else throw new Error('illegal constructor argument');
  }
}

class F extends A{
  constructor(...args:ACtorParams){
    super(...args)
  }
}
// Now the compiler puts out the proper error
// *Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter 
// * of type 'number | DestructureArg'.
// var f=new F('hi');
```

This answer is less useful than the [selected best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65375591/4376643) but I am going to leave it here and explain WHY using `interface` is not so useful, even though in this particular case it may have been a little bit shorter distance (one extra line) from the code posted in the original question.

Let's try using an `interface` with multiple constructor signatures:

```
interface xsig{
  new (carg?:number):any
  new (...cargs:string[]):any
  new ({a,b}:{a?:bigint,b?:string}):any
}
declare type xsigParams=ConstructorParameters<xsig>
class XXX{
  constructor(...args:xsigParams){
  } 
}
```

That compiles without error, but when we try to instantiate with what should be a legal parameter ...

```
// *Type '0' has no properties in common with 
// *type '{ a?: bigint; b?: string; }'. 
var xxx=new XXX(0);  // compile fails :(
```

It seems that `ConstructorParameters<xsig>` only picked up the LAST signature in `xsig`, and silently ignored all the rest.

But, with the method shown in the selected answer

```
namespace Xsig{
  type Ctor1 = new (carg?:number) => any
  type Ctor2 = new (...cargs:string[]) => any
  type Ctor3 = new ({a,b}:{a?:bigint,b?:string}) => any
  export type XCtorParams=
    ConstructorParameters<Ctor1>
    |ConstructorParameters<Ctor2>
    |ConstructorParameters<Ctor3>
}
class XX{
  constructor(...args:Xsig.XCtorParams){
  } 
}
var xx=new XX(0);  // compiles :)
```

it compiles fine.